# Sound stopped working in both Win 7 and Win 8.1 on my box

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, audio, windows-8.1

Today I found out that the sound stopped working on both Win 7 and Win 8.1 systems installed on my home PC, whereas it still works perfectly fine on Debian running on the same machine. I haven't touched anything related, so I am not sure what could be the reason.

How can I debug what is wrong? I don't really know where to start. All the drivers in hardware manager seem fine. I am just using the sound card in my chipset (old Asus board based on Intel chipset, from the Core 2 Quad era) with standard Creative speakers connected using a mini jack.

EDIT:
Windows doesn't seem to recognize that my speakers are plugged in, maybe the graphics chip stopped reporting this correctly. Is there a way to force it to play regardless?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the computer? Maybe try turning the volume knob? Turn off and back on? Delete the audio device and reinstall? BIOS options favor built-in audiocard? Try remotely listening to music via Teamviewer? A discrete audio card could help, perhaps?

Comment: @user1306322, the hardware works fine in Debian, so I have no reason to believe that anything apart from software configuration is wrong for some reason.

Comment: Well, then have you just tried all of the listed things?

Comment: Try to remove the sound driver and install the driver again. Are you able to see your sound card in computer management?

Comment: @user2301394, how do I do it? It is the standard driver that comes with Windows.

Comment: remove the driver from computer management and then download driver directly from vendor site.